# Web HUE installation and set up is done. Bu the dashboard is not working

Tags: hive, dashboard, hue

I have recently set up the Hue set up on my hadoop cluster and everything seems fine. I was able to open the webhue ie., localhost:8888 and i can see the HDFS, HBase and Mysql. But I am still facing some issues on this. Could anyone please help me out in this regard.
Problems facing are :
Hive connection: I am using beeline and i was able to connect to hive databses using beeline on the shelll But in the web hue, it shows error loading databases. The configuration i have used in hue.ini file is

hive_server_host=localhost

## Port where HiveServer2 Thrift server runs on.

hive_server_port=10000

The second issue is even though i was able to connect to the mysql database, the issue i am facing is in the dashboard tab. I can see all the widgets and charting options like pie,bar etc. But when i drag and drop them on the page, its loading forever. I dont able to see any chart of the table data.

Please help me out as i have been trying since 10 days and i could not able to find any pointers yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Ruthikajawar I have a working hue.ini here:

https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/HDP3-Hue-Service/blob/Hue.4.6.0/configuration/live.hue.ini

The specifics for working hive are:

```
[beeswax]

  # Host where HiveServer2 is running.
  # If Kerberos security is enabled, use fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).
  hive_server_host=hdp.cloudera.com

  # Binary thrift port for HiveServer2.
  #hive_server_port=10000

  # Http thrift port for HiveServer2.
  #hive_server_http_port=10001

  # Host where LLAP is running
  ## llap_server_host = localhost

  # LLAP binary thrift port
  ## llap_server_port = 10500

  # LLAP HTTP Thrift port
  ## llap_server_thrift_port = 10501

  # Alternatively, use Service Discovery for LLAP (Hive Server Interactive) and/or Hiveserver2, this will override server and thrift port

  # Whether to use Service Discovery for LLAP
  ## hive_discovery_llap = true

  # is llap (hive server interactive) running in an HA configuration (more than 1)
  # important as the zookeeper structure is different
  ## hive_discovery_llap_ha = false

  # Shortcuts to finding LLAP znode Key
  # Non-HA - hiveserver-interactive-site - hive.server2.zookeeper.namespace ex hive2 = /hive2
  # HA-NonKerberized - (llap_app_name)_llap ex app name llap0 = /llap0_llap
  # HA-Kerberized - (llap_app_name)_llap-sasl ex app name llap0 = /llap0_llap-sasl
  ## hive_discovery_llap_znode = /hiveserver2-hive2

  # Whether to use Service Discovery for HiveServer2
  hive_discovery_hs2 = true

  # Hiveserver2 is hive-site hive.server2.zookeeper.namespace ex hiveserver2 = /hiverserver2
  hive_discovery_hiveserver2_znode = /hiveserver2

  # Applicable only for LLAP HA
  # To keep the load on zookeeper to a minimum
  # ---- we cache the LLAP activeEndpoint for the cache_timeout period
  # ---- we cache the hiveserver2 endpoint for the length of session
  # configurations to set the time between zookeeper checks
  ## cache_timeout = 60

  # Host where Hive Metastore Server (HMS) is running.
  # If Kerberos security is enabled, the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) is required.
  #hive_metastore_host=hdp.cloudera.com

  # Configure the port the Hive Metastore Server runs on.
  #hive_metastore_port=9083

  # Hive configuration directory, where hive-site.xml is located
  hive_conf_dir=/etc/hive/conf

  # Timeout in seconds for thrift calls to Hive service
  ## server_conn_timeout=120

  # Choose whether to use the old GetLog() thrift call from before Hive 0.14 to retrieve the logs.
  # If false, use the FetchResults() thrift call from Hive 1.0 or more instead.
  ## use_get_log_api=false

  # Limit the number of partitions that can be listed.
  ## list_partitions_limit=10000

  # The maximum number of partitions that will be included in the SELECT * LIMIT sample query for partitioned tables.
  ## query_partitions_limit=10

  # A limit to the number of rows that can be downloaded from a query before it is truncated.
  # A value of -1 means there will be no limit.
  ## download_row_limit=100000

  # A limit to the number of bytes that can be downloaded from a query before it is truncated.
  # A value of -1 means there will be no limit.
  ## download_bytes_limit=-1

  # Hue will try to close the Hive query when the user leaves the editor page.
  # This will free all the query resources in HiveServer2, but also make its results inaccessible.
  ## close_queries=false

  # Hue will use at most this many HiveServer2 sessions per user at a time.
  # For Tez, increase the number to more if you need more than one query at the time, e.g. 2 or 3 (Tez has a maximum of 1 query by session).
  ## max_number_of_sessions=1

  # Thrift version to use when communicating with HiveServer2.
  # Version 11 comes with Hive 3.0. If issues, try 7.
 thrift_version=11

  # A comma-separated list of white-listed Hive configuration properties that users are authorized to set.
  ## config_whitelist=hive.map.aggr,hive.exec.compress.output,hive.exec.parallel,hive.execution.engine,mapreduce.job.queuename

  # Override the default desktop username and password of the hue user used for authentications with other services.
  # e.g. Used for LDAP/PAM pass-through authentication.
  ## auth_username=hive
  ## auth_password=hive

  # Use SASL framework to establish connection to host.
  use_sasl=true
```

For the second part of your question.  You should monitor the /var/log/hue/error.log while using the UI to capture and resolve any errors.

Comment: Hi Steven Thankyou so much for the reply. I have used the same configuration. The one thing that amazes me is i dont see my hive server2 is up or not. If i see through ambari, it shows as up and my port 10000 is also listening and my beeline is also working. But i am not sure why hue is not able to connect to hive. It gives me error as connection aborted.

Comment: The last line is a SASL value that I had to set to true to get hive to work.   Notice I use the zookeeper discovery method.  I had previously tried sending the hive host & port and did not work.  Maybe the sasl setting was it, but I was happy to just get it working....     I am trying to get my dashboard working now to trouble shoot that widget.

Comment: Also wanted to mention i have been connecting to hive using jdbc.. so is it possible to connect hue to hive through jdbc?